# Open USB mass storage using an intent on Android

Tags: android, usb

I'd like to open the USB mass storage activity programmatically. Currently the user has to click on the notification in the notification drawer. Is there an intent to open this activity?

Note : I am aware MountService is a part of the hidden APIs, and hence I can't mount to usb using code.However, I am hoping I can at least open this activity.

[image: This is the activity I'd like to launch.]